# Rails ajax callback after link_to remote

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to figure out this ajax callback business, and haven't had any luck getting it to work. I've looked at tons of SO questions, tutorials, etc. but am apparently not grasping how this works. I'm trying to update the contents of a div that contains a partial. This is a standard like/unlike type function where the user will click on link and it should update the icon via ajax. My ajax remote requests are working fine, but I can't get the callbacks to work. Here's my `show.html.erb` file:

```
<table class="v-table">
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <div class="favorite">
                    <%= render 'vendors/favorite' %>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><h2><%= image_tag @vendor.image_url %></h2></td>
        <td><%= @vendor.address %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the partial `favorite`:

```
<% if current_user.voted_for?(@vendor) %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("Heart (2).png"), 
        { :controller => :vendors, 
        :action => 'vote_against_vendor', :vendor_id => @vendor.id},
        { :method => 'delete', :remote => true }%>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("Heart (1).png"), 
        { :controller => :vendors, 
        :action => 'vote_for_vendor', :vendor_id => @vendor.id},
        { :method => 'post', :remote => true} %>
<% end %>
```

Here's my relevant controller actions:

```
respond_to :js

def show

    @vendor = Vendor.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

def vote_for_vendor

    vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    current_user.vote_for(vendor)
    render :toggle
end

def vote_against_vendor

    vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
    current_user.unvote_for(vendor)
    render :toggle
end
```

My toggle.js.erb file:

```
$("#favorite").html("<%= escape_javascript render('favorite') %>");
```

I'm really new to using js and ajax, please help! Thanks in advance.

**ERROR LOG**

After committing my remote transaction correctly, I get this error:

```
Rendered vendors/_favorite.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered vendors/toggle.js.erb (2.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 47ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
    1: <% if current_user.voted_for?(@vendor) %>
    2:  <%= link_to image_tag("Heart (2).png"), 
    3:      { :controller => :vendors, 
    4:      :action => 'vote_against_vendor', :vendor_id => @vendor.id},
  app/views/vendors/_favorite.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_vendors__favorite_html_erb___385976980778737159_2184308220'
  app/views/vendors/toggle.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_vendors_toggle_js_erb___3800164439665893406_2169792040'
  app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb:39:in `vote_for_vendor'


  Rendered /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (11.1ms)
```

Not sure what this means: `ActionView::Template::Error (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):`

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: Hmmm... good point. It's saying, `Missing template vendors/vote_for_vendor`. I thought I had said to `render :toggle`.

Comment: Stupid question (mine) but what is the type of the request? Is it interpreted as `JS`?

Comment: Try `render action: 'toogle'` just to see

Comment: Added `render action: 'toggle'`. Posted updated error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, you need to assign the model to an `instance` not `local` variable in your controller.

```
@vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
```

The rest looks good to me.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I originally tried to set up both of my vote_for methods that way, but kept getting errors so went with local variables. For whatever reason, no errors this time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I guess you may be missing **render 'vendors/favorite'** in your toggle.js.erb file. Everything else seems to be okay for me.

Comment: Toggle.js.erb is supposed to update the div `#favorite`, which renders the `_favorite` partial, no?

Comment: Yes, may be you need to use **render partial: :toggel**

Answer (score -1):

Ajax is the client side way to send server a request and get a response in several commands.
You should do the calling on the client side (so mainly write code on javascript or client side language).

Don't forget that ajax is an asynchronous by default (you can change it - not recommanded at first try. Actually when you send your request to server, you go to next line of your code, and the response is recieved not exactly at the expected time, as usual programs).

Here is a tinny code:

```
var tout;
....

function checkAjax() {
    'use strict';

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            if (tout) {
                clearTimeout(tout);
            }
// do something
        }
    };

    function ajaxTimeout() {
        xmlhttp.abort();
// write error to client
    }

    clearTimeout(tout); // if tout is global.

    tout = setTimeout(function () {
        ajaxTimeout();
    }, 10000); // 10 seconds, or what you persume to be fine.

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.php", true); // it can be "GET" or aspx, or whatever.
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xmlhttp.send("");
}
```

Good luck!!!